# Is there an offset writeback on x86?

Tags: assembly, x86, arm, addressing-mode

With ARM I can access a memory location like this:

```
LDR r0, [r1, #4]!
```

Meaning I want to load the value pointed to by r1, with an offset of 4 bytes, and the ! means that I want the value of r1 to be updated after this instruction with the new value (i.e., +4).

Is there an equivalent on x86 (AT&T syntax if possible)? For instance:

```
movl 4(%ebx), %eax
```

This will load the value pointed by %ebx with an offset of 4 bytes into %eax. How do I update the value of %ebx after the load though?

Thanks.

Comment: I think you mean `4(%ebx)`, right?  Aside from that, I don't know if intel has auto-incrementing addressing modes.  I'll take a quick look at the docs...

Comment: Ain't 4(%ebx) equivalent to (%ebx,4)?

Comment: My assembler won't take it: `example.s:3:scale factor of 4 without an index register`.

Comment: Gotcha. I think that inside the parenthesis you may only include another register as offset then. Thanks

Comment: Then you'd have an index register, yes.  The multiplication by 1 is implicit, or you can add the 2 or 4 yourself if you want something fancier.

Comment: @DanielS: Numbers inside the parenthesis for AT&T Syntax x86 assembly mean a "scale factor"; you say `offset(%basereg, %indexreg, scale)` meaning the address to use is `offeset + basereg + scale * indexreg`. The only options for the scale value are `0/1/2/4/8`. The way addresses are written is the weirdest bit of the AT&T Syntax; in Intel's style, you actually write `[ basereg + scale * indexreg + offset ]`.

Comment: @FrankH, thanks, makes more sense now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the instruction you're looking for is [`LODSD`](http://faydoc.tripod.com/cpu/lodsd.htm) which means "load DWORD from string".  You don't get to pick the registers though: The pointer is in `ESI` and the destination register is `EAX`.

> After the byte, word, or doubleword is transferred from the memory location into the
>   AL, AX, or EAX register, the (E)SI register is incremented or decremented automati-
>   cally according to the setting of the DF flag in the EFLAGS register. (If the DF flag is
>   0, the (E)SI register is incremented; if the DF flag is 1, the ESI register is decre-
>   mented.) The (E)SI register is incremented or decremented by 1 for byte operations,
>   by 2 for word operations, or by 4 for doubleword operations.

Sorry, I've got Intex syntax ingrained in my head right now. Assuming flat 32-bit protected mode:

```
mov   esi, _source_data_       ; ESI points to source data
cld                            ; Clear the direction flag
                               ; (ESI will increment)
lodsd                          ; Essentially   mov eax, [ds:esi]
                               ;               add esi, 4
```

Comment: Now while this instruction exists ... the sequence `mov (%esi),%eax; lea 4(%esi),%esi` might be faster. The so-called _string instructions_ have rather high instruction latencies, and they're tied to using registers `%edi` (for stores) and `%esi` (for loads) _only_. No, this is definitely _not as flexible_ as ARM's generic post/pre-in/decrement addressing.